# Grails 3.x replacement for WebUtils URL Mapping methods?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm upgrading a project from Grails 1.3.7 to 3.2.6.  In conf/spring/resources.groovy, it specifies the default exception handler:

```
exceptionHandler(MyExceptionResolver) {
    exceptionMappings = ['com.my.app.ApplicationException': '/error/applicationException',
                         'java.lang.Exception': '/error'
    ]
}
```

Trying to compile MyExceptionResolver with 3.2.6 produces a couple of errors due to methods that no longer exist in WebUtils.

```
UrlMappingsHolder urlMappings = null;
try {
    urlMappings = WebUtils.lookupUrlMappings(servletContext);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ignore
}
```

and

```
WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(
    request, response, info, mv.getModel());
```

I can't find any information on how to do this with Grails 3.x.  The only method I find on WebUtils that even seems to apply to URL mappings is

```
getForwardURI(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
```

Is there an analog to the lookupUrlMappings or forwardRequstForUrlMappingInfo method in Grails 3.0?  Do I need to be looking at another class?